# Proper way to use appendTo in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Am I using the jquery appendTo method correctly in the code below?

I am asking because it appears to displays correctly when I test it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/x7865gka/1/) but when I use the same code on my local server (in FF, IE and Chrome) it displays with elongated boxes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am assuming I am doing something wrong.
Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="ws-css-table"  >
  <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>    
</div>   

<br/>
<button id="css-icol">Col +</button><br/><br/>
```

jquery

```
$('#css-icol').click(function(){
    $(".ws-css-table-td:last").clone().appendTo('.ws-css-table-tr');

  var tblArr = $('.ws-css-table > .ws-css-table-tr').map(function ()
   {
    return $(this).children().map(function ()
    {
        return $(this);
    });
});     

lastCol = $('.ws-css-table-tr:first > .ws-css-table-td').length;
 for (r=0; r<$('.ws-css-table-tr').length; r++)
    tblArr[r][lastCol-1].text('X');
 });
```

css

```
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}
.ws-css-table-td { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: The code looks good, it seems like you may be getting affected by CSS elements not shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have any other CSS elements that I know of. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Also when I add more columns to the "grid" they 'X''s appear inside the boxes.

Comment: Working nicely? http://jsfiddle.net/110ewzuk/

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Developer tools to check the type of document you are rendering (especially important for IE) and what css is being utilized to render (Firebug/HTML/Computed) or (Firebug/HTML/Layout).

Comment: I'm not sure about cloning single cell element and appending to collection of rows. Can you check if [this javascript code](http://jsfiddle.net/x7865gka/2/) works any better? Other than that, maybe you have [`doctype`](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype) different than jsfiddle's.

Comment: I thought for sure that would work nrodic. It is so much cleaner. I still get the same issue though. I am posting a screen shot (above) of the code generated. It seems somehow <p></p> are being inserted. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you see any `<p></p>` **before** adding columns? It might be problem with rendering the view.

Comment: Interesting. I do see some <p></p> before adding columns (I posted above). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Sure. The code just selects last `div` and appends after `p`.

Comment: But I don't have any <p></p> code in the source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92759/discussion-between-nrodic-and-user1763812).

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks to nrodic the issue is fixed. I was inserting this code in a  WordPress page which apparently inserts it's own <p> tags. This had an adverses effect on what I was doing. The solution was to remove the tag with: $(".ws-css-table-tr > p").remove(); Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in this line:

```
$(".ws-css-table-td:last").clone().appendTo('.ws-css-table-tr');
```

You select the last cell in the table and clone it to every row. When you want to copy the column, you have to select last cells in all rows, then you have to iterate over the cloned cells. Finally, the method `after` is more elegant here...

```
$(".ws-css-table-td:last-child")
  .each(function(){
    var $this=$(this)
    $this.after($this.clone())
  })
```

To create an empty column use:

```
$(".ws-css-table-td:last-child")
  .after("<div class='ws-css-table-td'/>")
```

Comment: Elegant selector, indeed.

Comment: @nrodic thanks, jquery is here to make the code elegant